# Preciso pegar dados do banco de dados e exibir em JSON porém dá erro

Tags: php, mysql, api

Estou usando o SLIM PHP para desenvolver uma API. A classe que pega informações do banco para exibir em JSON não funciona!

Eu acesso esse host local, que eu criei: api/comunicados/geral

O geral é uma classe que contém esse código:

```
<?php
$app->get('/comunicados/geral', function() {

    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    $query = 'select * from geral';
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    if (isset($data)) {
        echo json_enconde($data);
    }
});
```

Porém, ela dá esse erro toda vez que é chamada:
Slim Application Error

A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.

Eu não sei o que acontece, por favor alguém pode me ajudar a resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_enconde` não existe!

`json_encode` é o correto.

Comment: Era isso, como eu pude não ver... Agora não tem erro, porém quando eu executo o geral ele não vem as informações da tabela em JSON, na tela não aparece nada

Comment: Você tem que ir testanto. Sem ter acesso aos seus dados não tem como saber o que há de errado. Vai dando echo prá descobrir onde está o erro. Apesar de eu nunca ter usado o echo com slim framework, sempre usei o "return response", nem sei se com o echo funciona....